# Change marker style by a dataframe column (categorical) in seaborn stripplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, jupyter

I was looking to visualise a categorical variable as marker style in seaborn stripplot, but it does not seem to be possible easily. Is there an easy way to do this. For example, I'm trying to run this code

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="time", style="sex", jitter=True, data=tips)
```

which fails. An alternative is to use relplot which does provide the option but has no way to insert `jitter` which makes the visualisation less nice.

```
sns.relplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="time", data=tips, style="sex")
```

works providing this

[image]

Is there any way of doing this using stripplot/catplot/swarmplot?

EDIT: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650895/how-do-i-add-multiple-markers-to-a-stripplot-in-seaborn) question is related. However the solution there does not seem to allow generation of a legend for size (and is quite dated).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add multiple markers to a stripplot in seaborn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650895/how-do-i-add-multiple-markers-to-a-stripplot-in-seaborn)

Comment: It sort of does. But it has a downside of not being able to get a legend wrt the marker style. Is there no better way to do this over the last 5 years?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sns.relplot` is a figure-level function which relies on the axes-level function `sns.scatterplot`. `sns.scatterplot` has a parameter `x_jitter` which unfortunately currently has no effect (seaborn 0.11.2).

You can mimic the functionality by grasping the positions of the points, add some random jitter and assigning these positions again.

Here is an example:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="time", data=tips, style="sex")
for points in ax.collections:
    vertices = points.get_offsets().data
    if len(vertices) > 0:
        vertices[:, 0] += np.random.uniform(-0.3, 0.3, vertices.shape[0])
        points.set_offsets(vertices)
xticks = ax.get_xticks()
ax.set_xlim(xticks[0] - 0.5, xticks[-1] + 0.5) # the limits need to be moved to show all the jittered dots
sns.move_legend(ax, bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1.02), loc='upper left')  # needs seaborn 0.11.2
sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.scatterplot with jitter]

With `sns.relplot` you could iterate through all the subplots:

```py
g = sns.relplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="time", data=tips, style="sex")
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    for points in ax.collections:
        vertices = points.get_offsets().data
        if len(vertices) > 0:
            vertices[:, 0] += np.random.uniform(-0.3, 0.3, vertices.shape[0])
            points.set_offsets(vertices)
    xticks = ax.get_xticks()
    ax.set_xlim(xticks[0] - 0.5, xticks[-1] + 0.5) # the limits need to be moved to show all the jittered dots
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using seaborn's [object interface](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html#) (starting version 0.12), you can now do this as follows:

```py
import seaborn.objects as so
(
    so.Plot(tips, x="day", y="total_bill", color="time", marker="sex")
    .add(so.Dot(pointsize=7, edgecolor="white"), so.Jitter(.3))
).theme(
    {**sns.axes_style("ticks"), 'axes.spines.right': False, 'axes.spines.top': False}
)
```

[image: Stripplot produced by the code snippte]